# ASP.NET MVC how to handle full submit with html beginform and ajax beginform

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, ajax.beginform, html.beginform

In my code, I use `Ajax.BeginForm` for collecting entries (with modal window for new entries) then refresh the list.

Controller :

```
    public ActionResult BusinessCategoryNewUpdateRow(BusinessCategoryViewModel vmodel)
    {
        try
        {
            vmodel.Subcategories.Add(vmodel.NewEditEntry);
            return PartialView("BusinessCategory/SubBusinessCategoryView", vmodel);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

View :

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("BusinessCategoryNewUpdateRow", "BusinessReference", new AjaxOptions
        { UpdateTargetId = "subCategoryPart", OnSuccess = "clearDialog" }, new { id = "showWin" }))
        {
            <div class="form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        <div class="form-group fill">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainCategory.name, new { @class = "floating-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MainCategory.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainCategory.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        <div class="form-group fill">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainCategory.business_cat_code, new { @class = "floating-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MainCategory.business_cat_code, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainCategory.business_cat_code, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row  p-b-10">
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        <div class="form-group fill">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainCategory.description, new { @class = "floating-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MainCategory.description, "Text", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainCategory.description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <h5>Sub-Category</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 p-b-5">
                        @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary has-ripple ml-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popWinSubCategory">Add<span class="ripple ripple-animate" style="height: 173.675px; width: 173.675px; animation-duration: 0.7s; animation-timing-function: linear; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 0.4; top: -49.1375px; left: 53.1625px;"></span></button>*@
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary has-ripple" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popWinSubCategory">Add<span class="ripple ripple-animate" style="height: 173.675px; width: 173.675px; animation-duration: 0.7s; animation-timing-function: linear; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 0.4; top: -49.1375px; left: 53.1625px;"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                @*popup window*@
                <div id="popWinSubCategory" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="popWinSubCategoryLabel" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="popWinSubCategoryLabel">Add/Edit Subcategory</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-11">
                                        <div class="form-group fill">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewEditEntry.name, new { @class = "floating-label" })
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewEditEntry.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewEditEntry.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-11">
                                        <div class="form-group fill">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewEditEntry.business_cat_code, new { @class = "floating-label" })
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewEditEntry.business_cat_code, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewEditEntry.business_cat_code, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-11">
                                        <div class="form-group fill">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewEditEntry.description, new { @class = "floating-label" })
                                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewEditEntry.description, "Text", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewEditEntry.description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary" id="btnSaveAdd">Save</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary has-ripple" data-dismiss="modal">Close<span class="ripple ripple-animate" style="height: 74.9625px; width: 74.9625px; animation-duration: 0.7s; animation-timing-function: linear; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 0.4; top: -26.3813px; left: -14.7937px;"></span></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @*popup window*@
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="subCategoryPart">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                @Html.Partial("BusinessCategory/SubBusinessCategoryView", Model)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

This part is ok, the problem is when I include/add `Html.BeginForm` outside `Ajax.BeginForm`, the add button of modal window triggers the `Html.BeginForm` instead of the `Ajax.BeginForm`.

What is the best approach to handle collections then perform a final submit using `Html.BeginForm` and `Ajax.BeginForm`?